# scrapy how to make my own scheduler middelware

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am using Python 2.7 with Scrapy 0.20

#### My Question

How to build my own scheduler ?

#### What I have tried

I read through internet and I found this:

1. I have to make my own python class and assign it in the setting using SCHEDULER_MIDDLEWARES
2. Create that class,which is **maybe** inhertes from  `scrapy.core.scheduler`

But I couldn't find any example on internet nor any official documentation

Comment: You will probably have to modify scrapy. The scheduler middleware feature was removed in release 0.14.
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html

What changes are you trying to make? They may be possible via Downloader Middleware.

Answer (score 2):

You can set [the `SCHEDULER` setting](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#scheduler):

```
SCHEDULER = 'myproject.schedulers.MyScheduler'
```

and copy the code from [scheduler.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/scheduler.py).