# Best way to make a Python scheduler

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am working with scrapy 0.20 on python 2.7

#### Question

What is the best python scheduler.

#### My need

I need to run my spider, **which is a python script**, each 3 hours.

#### What I have thought

1. I tried using windows scheduler features which comes with Windows 7 and It works good. I am able to run a python script each 3 hours but I may deploy my python script on Linux server so I may not be able to use this option.
2. I create a Java application using [Quartz-Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/). It works good but this is a third library, which my manager may refuse.
3. I created a windows service and I made it fire the script each three hours. It works but I may deploy my python script on a Linux server so I may not be able to use this option.

I am asking about the best practice to fire a python script

Comment: Is this related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414480/scrapy-how-to-make-my-own-scheduler-middelware)? Is that you too?

Comment: @poke I have read that question before. and if you knew scrapy, you wouldn't ask if that question is mine.

Comment: Well, you can’t blame me. Both questions are about making a scheduler with Python 2.7 and scrapy 0.20. And both questions do share a very similar—and uncommon—formatting for the text. Wasn’t accusing you of anything though, just curious.

Comment: @poke let me explain. First, scrapy is always working with python2.7 because the version that works with python 3 is still beta so it is normal to see scrapy with python 2.7 always with many users. Second, as I told you, I have seen that question and that is why I wrote forma my question like it. In addition, I am new here, so I don't know how to write questions. I have tried 4 or 5 times and everytime, I got error that the question is not good for the quality of the website. that is why i tried to copy and paste the same format with a question that takes +2.

Answer (score 4):

> I tried using windows scheduler features which comes with Windows 7 and it works good.

So that works fine for you already. Good, no need to change your script to do scheduling work yourself.

> but I may deploy my python script on Linux server so I may not be able to use this option.

On Linux, you can use [cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to achieve this.

---

The other way would be to simply keep your script running the whole time, but pause it for the three hours in which you are doing nothing. So you don’t need to set up anything on the target machine, but just need to run the script in the background, and it will keep running and doing its job.

This is exactly how job schedulers work btw. They are launched early when the operating system starts, and then they just keep running forever and every short time interval (a minute or so) they check if there is any job on their list that needs to run now. And if that’s the case, they spawn a new process and run the job.

So if you wanted to make such a scheduler in Python, you would just keep it running forever, and once every time interval (in your case 3 hours because you only have a single job anyway), you start your job. That can be in a separate process, in a separate thread, or indirectly in a separate thread using asynchronous functions.

Comment: First, I need to do scheduler independent of the platform. I am using python which is independet of the platform and I already finished my project. So, after all the job, it is worth to make the scheduler with python not with the server features. Secondly,  I can't pause the script because it is `scrapy` in which you crawl websites and get data. all the job is asynctask and there is no way to know which data has been retrieved or not at a specific moment

Comment: I don’t know about scrapy, but you could still do a loop: `while True: startScrapy(); sleep(3 hours);`… Also, in my opinion, scheduling the job is not part of your application but of the target environment. If that environment wants to run it every `n` hours, it should do that on its own. Especially given that your “scheduler” could be terminated by a third party, using an available and trusted scheduler is the better option.

Comment: in addition, the websites are having more data each minutes. So, I need to run the script again and again each three hours, not pause it because I would lost the data that has been added after the script runs the very first time.

Comment: I would rather wait for another answer that has python not the target server. +1 to your efforts. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The best way to deploy/schedule your scrapy project is to use [scrapyd](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html) server.

1. You should install scrapyd.

   ```
   sudo-apt get install scrapyd
   ```
2. You change your project config file to something like this :

   ```
   [deploy:somename]
   url = http://localhost:6800/  ## this the default 
   project = scrapy_project
   ```
3. you deploy your project under the scrapyd server:

   ```
   scrapy deploy somename
   ```
4. You change your poll interval in /etc/scrapyd/conf.d/default-000 to 3 hours ( default to 5 seconds):

   ```
   poll_interval = 10800
   ```
5. You configure your spider something like :

   ```
   curl http://localhost:6800/schedule.json -d project=scrapy_project -d spider=myspider
   ```
6. You can use the web service to monitor your jobs:

   ```
   http://localhost:6800/
   ```

PS: I just test it under ubuntu So I am not sure that a windows version exist. If not you can install a VM with ubuntu to launch the spiders.

Comment: This is the best answer. Scrapyd is great to use imo. Figure out the web service's api then write a python script (or multiple scripts) that make a request to schedule.json. Then use cron job on linux or window's task manager to run your script(s) at certain times or intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's always the charming
[`sched`](http://pymotw.com/2/sched/)
([docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html)) module, which provides a generic scheduling interface.

Give it a `time` function and a `sleep` function, and it'll give you back a pretty nice and extensible scheduler.

It's not system-level, but if you can run it as a service, it should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, python suddenly stops working on my machine. Tomorrow I will fix it and come back to you.